# Local Client/Server interaction not functioning in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I can't seem to get my client to connect to my server. I'm developing a multiplayer game that will be played and hosted on a local area network. I'm trying to setup the preliminary steps to get all network transport functions going but it just doesn't seem to be working. When I run the client as a standalone app and the server in unity editor, i should see feedback in the editor console when the client connects to the server,

```
case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + "has connected.");
                OnConnection(connectionId);
```

but I'm not getting any feedback. I'm new at networking so I'm having trouble tracking down where things are going wrong. Any help would be great! thanks.

'NetworkServerController.cs'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Text;

public class NetworkServerController : MonoBehaviour {

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;
    private int port = 5701;

    private int hostID;
    private int webHostID;

    private int reliableChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableFragChannel;

    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private void Awake()
    {
        //NetworkServer.Reset();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();
        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableFragmented);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);
        webHostID = NetworkTransport.AddWebsocketHost(topo, port, null);

        isStarted = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isStarted)
            return;

        int recHostId;
        int connectionId;
        int channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;
        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);
        switch (recData)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.Nothing:         //1
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:    //2
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + "has connected.");
                OnConnection(connectionId);
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:       //3
                string msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(recBuffer, 0, dataSize);
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + "has sent : " + msg);
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent: //4
                Debug.Log("Player " + connectionId + "has disconnected.");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnConnection(int cnnID)
    {
        // Add to list

        // When player joins, tell ID

        // Request name and send name of all the other players
    }
}
```

'NetworkClientController.cs'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class NetworkClientController : MonoBehaviour {

    private const int MAX_CONNECTION = 100;
    private int port = 5701;
    private string IPAddress = "localhost";

    private int hostID;
    private int webHostID;

    private int reliableChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableFragChannel;

    private int connectionID;

    private float connectionTime;
    private bool isConnected = false;
    private bool isStarted = false;
    private byte error;

    private string playerName;

    private void Start()
    {
        Connect();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isConnected)
            return;

        int recHostId;
        int connectionId;
        int channelId;
        byte[] recBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        int dataSize;
        byte error;
        NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);
        switch (recData)
        {
            case NetworkEventType.Nothing:         //1
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.ConnectEvent:    //2
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.DataEvent:       //3
                break;
            case NetworkEventType.DisconnectEvent: //4
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        NetworkTransport.Init();
        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableFragmented);

        HostTopology topo = new HostTopology(cc, MAX_CONNECTION);

        hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);
        connectionID = NetworkTransport.Connect(hostID, IPAddress, port, 0, out error);

        connectionTime = Time.time;
        isConnected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change your IP Address from "localhost" to your actual IP Address?

Comment: @Programmer It doesn't seem to make a difference, still receiving no feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two network API in Unity which are LLAPI and HLAPI. *You are currently using the LLAPI*. With the LLAPI, you **cannot** create server and client on the-same machine/device.

You need two devices to test this on. Either two computers or one Android/iOS device then you can test it from the Editor or Build on your computer. The server and client just have to run on two different machines.

If you don't use two different devices for server and client and try to call the `NetworkTransport.AddHost` function, you will get the following error on the client:

> Cannot open socket on ip {*} and port {5701}; check please your
>   network, most probably port has been already occupied

Also, if `NetworkTransport.AddHost` fail and `NetworkTransport.Connect` is called, you will also get another error too:

> host id out of bound id {-1} max id should be greater 0 and less than
>   {0}

---

If you don't mind using HLAPI instead of LLAPI, you can actually get ride of the restriction by using the `NetworkManager.StartHost()` function which allows you to start the server and client on the-same application.

Answer (score 4):

You're following that tutorial on youtube, at about 20 minutes into the video he changes a line without making a comment on it.

In the client script change the following line:

```
hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, port, null);
```

To:

```
hostID = NetworkTransport.AddHost(topo, 0);
```

The reason for this, as I gather, is that you need to use different ports when using the same machine. When using 0 a random port will be selected.

If you still haven't got it working, try to make this change and see if it helps.

[Unity Docs reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkTransport.AddHost.html)